# {AS3} addChild() in a Class does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, private, addchild

so I have a class:

```
package
{
    public final class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var TextHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function Main():void
        {
            spawnHolder();
        }
        private function spawnHolder():void
        {
            TextHolder.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            TextHolder.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 80);
            TextHolder.graphics.endFill();
            stage.addChild(TextHolder);
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is.. I do not see anything on the stage.. This Main Class is the document class btw.

I'd appreciate it very much if anyone could help me out!
Thanks in advance.

~Gg

Comment: Just because it says `[object Sprite]` doesn't mean that it's on the display list. It just means that it's an object of the type `Sprite`.

Comment: Ran your code in FlashDevelop with a black background and it works fine. It could be something in your environment. I suggest debugging and checking if it actually gets added to the stage and checking the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stage is not available until the display object has been added to the stage. It will be null until that happens.

```
package
{
    public final class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var TextHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function Main():void
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,spawnHolder);
        }
        private function spawnHolder():void
        {
            TextHolder.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            TextHolder.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 80);
            TextHolder.graphics.endFill();
            stage.addChild(TextHolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better if you test for `if(stage)` before adding the event listener, and call `spawnHolder` directly if it evaluates to true: `if(stage)  spawnHolder() else this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,spawnHolder);`

Comment: @JcFx you also left out that the event listener isn't being removed :)

Comment: Heh. Pedants anonymous will throw me out of their inner circle ... :)

Comment: Heh the "if(stage) init;....." was what I tried right b4 seeing this post! Thanks anyways guys! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a color, probably your document background is also white.
Do not name vars with capital like `TextHolder`, use `textHolder` instead.
Try to do all work after stage initialized.